# how do I use a "double" value with JOptionPane.showInputDialog

Tags: java, joptionpane

This is my code:

```
       currentSalary = (double)(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your current salary", "Current Salary", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, "Numbers only!"));
       raise = currentSalary * .04;
       total = currentSalary + raise;
       NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
       System.out.println("Your raise is " + money.format(total));
```

currently, I need to make currentSalary a double value but I can't because JOptionPane only holds strings. How would I go about doing this while still using a dialog box? any working answer is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Double.parse().

Comment: The method parse(Object) is undefined for the type Double is what it gives me

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Comment: Thank you, I soon realized that I need to define JOptionPane with a string and later on do Double.parseDouble(). I appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem just a few days ago.

I used **Double.parseDouble()** to parse the variable as *String* , from *double*

The code should look as the following I think...

```
            double  currentSalary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your current salaryy\", \"Current Salary\", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, \"Numbers only!\""));
```

Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong, I'm just a beginner but this worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog`, this will accept primative variables.